# Migrating wordpress database to host without external mysql access

Tags: php, mysql, migrate

I am trying to migrate lots of websites to a new host which does not provide external access to the mysql database.

I have exported a backup from the originating host, which includes a mysql backup in this style:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: blueball_wrdp1
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.0.92-community

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_commentmeta`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`meta_id`),
  KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

I am trying to import it into the new host, which has an identically named database created. The easiest way I can think to do this is with php like this:

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect('account.host.com', 'account_wrdp1', '1234567890');

    if (!$con){
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("account_wrdp1", $con);

    if (mysql_query( file_get_contents('account_wrdp1.sql') ,$con)){
      echo "Tables created and populated.";
    } else {
      echo "Error populating database: " . mysql_error();
    }

    mysql_close($con);

?>
```

But when I do that I am getting error:

```
Error creating database: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_in' at line 25
```

N.B. At first I was having errors with the meta lines like `/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;` so I stripped them all out with sed, which is when I am seeing this new error.

So my question, is why is the seemingly good MySQL dump creating an error?

And is there a much easier way for me to approach the whole problem - being that the mysql server seems to be a separate virtual server to the one my website is hosted on, and I have absolutely no shell access etc...

Comment: Do you know what version of MySQL your new host is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have FTP access, wouldn't it be easiest to just upload a copy of PHPMyAdmin and use that to import the files?  It may or may not fix the error your getting, but it will make the importing process a lot easier.

Comment: I did try doing that, but unfortunately my phpmyadmin was giving me an error. I just checked the php version, and it should be compatible, but phpmyadmin was asking for a library file that it could not get. I will try to solve that problem separately, and if I do - will use phpmyadmin instead. Initially, I had avoided this approach, because I do not want to download all the files locally, and ten upload them remotely, I would rather hava scripted solution, which can move all databases from one server to another - without local intervention. Might end up doing that though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If PHPMyAdmin is not avaliable to you, check your CPanel to see if you can SSH into mysql.

[MySQL Remotely](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-and-ssh.html)

an alternative CLI for windows is [putty](http://www.putty.org/)